# What is docs.min.js?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am just starting to use bootstrap. I am trying to understand the Dashboard component:
1)  Why does the Dashboard html page that I downloaded contain:
`<script src="../../assets/js/docs.min.js"></script>`  – I thought all was included in the bootstrap.js. 
2)  What is docs.min.js by the way?
Regards,
Janusz

Comment: its probably bootstraps documentation javascript for their page, has nothing to do with the actual bootstrap framework. Look at the source and you will see in the comments : **JavaScript for Bootstrap's docs (http://getbootstrap.com)**

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately, I'm not entirely certain what you mean by the 'Dashboard' component. The standard list of Bootstrap components can be found [on their website](http://getbootstrap.com/components/), and there's nothing called "Dashboard" there. Most likely `doc.min.js` is something specific to the demo you're looking at. Since we have no idea what the demo looks like, and since we can't read your mind, it's a little hard to determine exactly what's going on. If you edit your post to include more info, it'll be easier for others to help.

Comment: I think this is what he is referring to: http://getbootstrap.com/assets/js/docs.min.js

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about HTML basics.

Comment: Not sure why you were downvoted... this is what stackoverflow should be for (even if they're basic questions).  Janusz even mentioned that they're just starting with bootstrap.

Comment: Agreed this is a valid question. This file is included in the theme example page, which is not a documentation page, so it's confusing as to whether it's really needed.

Answer (score 9):

The `docs.min.js` file contains scripts that are used by the Bootstrap documentation pages. It is not a component of Bootstrap — it should not be used by other sites.

Specifically, it contains minified copies of:

- the [Holder](http://imsky.github.io/holder/) image placeholder library
- the [ZeroClipboard](http://zeroclipboard.org/) clipboard interface library
- [A short script file used by the documentation](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/docs/assets/js/src/application.js) (which describes itself as "ALL JUST JUNK FOR OUR DOCS"!)

Comment: Sorry I might be missing something here. So why is it included in the html of Dashboard html I have downloaded? Dashboard is one of the components recommended by bootstrap – just open the page http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#examples – you will find it in ‘Custom components’ section.

Comment: Because the sample circle images in the Dashboard example are made using holder.js

Comment: What is holder.js - am I mad? If bootstrap is dependent only on jquery why is it dependent on all those other *.js.?\

Comment: Bootstrap isn't dependent on those libraries. The Bootstrap documentation site is.

Comment: What is the official site for Bootstrap?